# Platform browser has already been set. Overwriting the platform with [object Object]. when using tfjs-node in electron app

Tags: javascript, electron, tensorflow.js, tfjs-node

Platform browser has already been set. Overwriting the platform with [object Object].

Error when trying to load file that has tfjs-node as an import:

```
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');
```

This only occurs in electron files that are loaded by the browser. I can set it up so that "script loaded by browser".js sends a request to main.js that sends a request to "file with tfjs-node".js and it works fine.

Wondering if there is a way to load the files directly without the intermediary requests

```
"dependencies": {
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-node": "^1.2.3",
    "cmake-js": "^6.0.0",
    "electron-reload": "^1.5.0",
    "esm": "^3.2.25",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "fs-jetpack": "^2.1.0",
    "iohook": "^0.6.5",
    "jimp": "^0.9.3",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "keypress": "^0.2.1",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.0",
    "node-png": "^0.4.3",
    "parse-full-name": "^1.2.4",
    "requirejs": "^2.3.6",
    "robotjs": "^0.6.0",
    "statman-stopwatch": "^2.11.1",
    "tesseract.js": "^2.0.2"
  },
```

Answer (score 2):

I had same trouble when i used tfjs-react-native package on my device. My app just had closes when i tried use something from this package. In console was only warning "Platform browser has already been set. Overwriting the platform with [object Object]".

This was solved by setting backend before used tfjs-react-native. Maybe it will help you too.

```
await tf.setBackend('cpu');
```

Answer (score 0):

TensorflowJS chooses the best backend for processing automatically.
You can specifially use - 
**Web/Electron -**

```js
 await tf.setBackend('wasm');
```

or

```
await tf.setBackend('cpu');
```

before

```js
tf.ready()
```

statement to avoid errors. 
you can also view current backend being used by using -

```
console.log(tf.getBackend());
```

[reference](https://www.tensorflow.org/js/guide/platform_environment)